# Does a Rails 3.0.0.beta app only see bundled gems in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, irb

I have a library that I'm trying to get working with rails 3 (specifically feedzirra) which I can require ok in irb but it breaks the console in my app with the following error:

http://pastie.org/855976

Comment: Can you otherwise start the server fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails3 modifies the $LOAD_PATH so it only contains gems listed in the Gemfile.
($LOAD_PATH is an array of directories where Ruby searches for libraries).

So you must add the Gem to the Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
You can check if the gem is in your path by typing `puts $LOAD_PATH.grep(/feedzirra/)` in the rails console.

For more information on using Bundler in Rails3 check out these:

- http://railsdispatch.com/posts/bundler
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Answer (score 1):

Found a bit of info on using feedzirra with rails 3. It looks like your problem might be with the Loofah library feedzira uses. It uses the deprecated config.framework.

Here's a link with some more info http://www.mythoughtpot.com/2010/02/10/feedzirra-on-rails3/